# Get AMQ Message via ActiveMQ Broker Plugin

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have implemented a custom ActiveMQ broker plugin using [BrokerFilter](http://%20https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerFilter.html) Class. I have override the send method shown below.

```
public void send(final ProducerBrokerExchange producerExchange, final Message messageSend) throws Exception {

     logger.info("Message  : " + messageSend);
     // Returns the JMS Type of Mesage
     logger.info("Message Type  : " +  messageSend.getType());

     // Lookig for method to get the message text
        ?

}
```

The first line of logs shows the message text in the object but there seems no method avaiblae to get the message text.

```
    INFO | Message : ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = false, messageId = ID:192.168.10.6-63132-1613444356003-4:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:192.168.10.6-63132-1613444356003-4:1:1:1, destination = topic://reporting, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1613444364819, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = , replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = NewAgent, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, **text = Hello** }

    INFO | getType : New
```

Can someone guide me to the appropriate class or method to get/intercept the message text?  My goal is to get the message text/body and store it in redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out what type of message it is and cast it in order to get the text (or whatever) out of the message. Try something like:

```
public void send(final ProducerBrokerExchange producerExchange, final Message messageSend) throws Exception {

  logger.info("Message  : " + messageSend);
  // Returns the JMS Type of Mesage
  logger.info("Message Type  : " +  messageSend.getType());
  logger.info("Message Class : " + messageSend.getClass().toString());
  // Lookig for method to get the message text
  
  if (messageSend instanceof ActiveMQTextMessage) {
    ActiveMQTextMessage txtMsg = (ActiveMQTextMessage)messageSend;
    Logger.info("Message Text : " + txtMsg.getText();
  }

}
```

[Text message](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQTextMessage.html) docs.